# How should I begin when trying to determine a proposition whose truth value is unknown?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, discrete-mathematics

I've been doing many exercises that ask me something like

> With whatever sets X, Y, A, and B, determine the truth value of
>
> $(X \subseteq (A \triangle B) \land Y \subseteq A) \implies X \cap Y = \emptyset$

Since obviously I don't know whether the end value will be true or false, I have a pretty hard time when determining it, because it seems like I require some "intuition", assume that it is either true or false, and attempt to prove that. If my assumption is wrong, then my entire proof leads to nowhere, and I waste my time.

I usually end up determining their value because I realize that my attempt to prove them true is leading nowhere, so then I attempt to prove them false. Time wasted, I guess.

Is there a proper way to start with this kind of problem?

Comment: If you assume its true and this leads to a contradiction, then effectively you have proven it is false. Similarly, if you start off assuming it is false and this leads to a contradiction, then you have effectively proven it true. I believe this is called **proof by contradiction**.

Comment: I take it you mean $X\cap Y\neq \varnothing$. On a side note: consider $\varnothing\neq X=Y=A\setminus B$.

Comment: @Mufasa: Yeah, but I have noticed that usually when I make the wrong assumption, my proof doesn't lead to anything useful (not even a contradiction!), and instead it looks like a dead end.

Comment: I don't usually let this kind of thing bother me too much. I consider it as part of the **discovery** process in mathematics and, as you get better, you learn when and how to take the right routes towards a solution.

Comment: @GitGud: Ah, yes. Edited.

Comment: @Mufasa: There's no such thing as an initial strategy? :(

Comment: It depends on the problem at hand, you will learn to recognise what is usually the best strategy to use for each _type_ of problem as you practice and learn. Git Gud gave a good initial strategy for this _type_ of problem.

Comment: @Omega If you can't feel wether it is true or not, try to prove it is true. As you get better, those bits which you're having trouble proving will most likely be bits which aren't true (as opposed to you just not being able to prove them), and from there you can start thinking about counterexamples.

Comment: Don't think of mathematics as having some sort of rule book, but pure logic instead. Things *need to make sense* before you proceed!

Comment: @JosuéMolina -- well put! :)

Answer (score 1):

With this sort of problem you can often make a good start by drawing a Venn diagram. If the circles in the diagram below represent the sets $A$ and $B$, the red region represents $A\mathbin{\triangle}B$. If $X$ is a subset of the red region, and $Y$ is a subset of the lefthand circle, must $X\cap Y=\varnothing$? Clearly not: $X$ and $Y$ might both be the lefthand half of the red region, i.e., $A\setminus B$. Now just build a concrete counterexample using that idea: you might, for instance, let $A=\{0,1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, and $X=Y=\{0\}$.

[image]

With a bit more experience you won’t need the diagram. You might, for instance, see right away that if $A\cap B=\varnothing$, then $A\mathbin{\triangle}B=A\cup B$, so as long as $A$ is non-empty, you can set $X=Y=A$ and get a counterexample. Or you might reason it out like this. Points of $A\mathbin{\triangle}B$ are points that are in exactly one of $A$ and $B$; surely we can find $A$ and $B$ so that some of these are in $A$, and we can then let $Y$ be the set of those points.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry - you'll gain some sort of feel for how to do these questions until they become easy, or obvious.

In fact, you can make this very question obvious now.  For a problem in elementary set theory, such as this one, you can easily visualize the question by drawing an [Euler diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_diagram): draw the set $A,B$ as intersecting circles, and fill in the region corresponding to $A\triangle B$ (if you haven't seen this before, I'll just tell you - it's everything except the region in the middle).  If a set $X$ is contained in this region and a set $Y$ is contained in $A$, must it be the case that $X$ and $Y$ don't intersect?  If it must, then try and *use* your diagram to find a proof.  If you can find a counterexample in the Euler diagram, use it to construct an explicit counterexample: draw $X$ and $Y$ on the diagram in the specified regions in such a way that they *do* intersect, and then fill in every separate region on the diagram with a distinct number.  Define $A,B,X,Y$ to be the sets of the numbers that those circles enclose on the diagram, and show mathematically that this choice of $A,B,X,Y$ doesn't satisfy the conjecture.